# Is there any way to add header to SOAP HTTP response in Axis2 generated web service?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, jax-ws, apache-axis

I have a Web service which was generated by Apache Axis2 from WSDL using eclipse-mars, running on tomcat 8.0:
Skeleton of methods, generated classes of types and message reciever in out which is auto-generated implementation of AbstractInOutMessageReciever.

Any request returns http status 200. If I send XML without required fields, it gives 500 internal server error and xml with faultstring (adbexception).

Service implementation contains in skeleton.
I need to add status code 400 when some conditions met, but I don't find where to put headers in HTTP response. I have a generated response object, but it contains nothing except fields and setters for them.

Generated MessageReciever contains invokeBusinessLogic method, which sends a SOAPEnvelope object in response. Is there any way to add some http headers to this envelope?

upd: added code example

i have a skeleton method:

```
public class GenServiceSkeleton {   
    public TaskResponse taskResponse(TaskRequest request) {
        // some business logic
        // for ex
        TaskResponse resp = new TaskResponse();
        resp.setTask("1");
        return resp;
    }
}
```

where TaskResponse is a bean implemenation of ADBBean and reciever is subclass of AbstractInOutMessageReceiver

```
public class GenServiceRecieverInOut extends org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiever {
    public void invokeBusinessLogic(org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext msgContect, org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext newMsgContext) {
    try {
        // get the implementation class for the Web Service
        Object obj = getTheImplementationObject(msgContext)
        GenServiceSkeleton skel = (GenServiceSkeleton)skel;
        //Out Envelop
        org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope envelope = null;
        // ....
        // below some code
        // ....
        // ....
            if("getTask".equals(methodName)){
                TaskResponse taskResponse11 = null;
        TaskRequest wrappedParam = (TaskRequest)fromOM(msgContext.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement(),TaskRequest.class);  
                taskResponse11 =skel.taskResponse(wrappedParam);
        envelope = toEnvelope(getSOAPFactory(msgContext), taskResponse11, false,new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://example.com", "TaskResponse"));   
}
```

Comment: We need to see at least a little code to assist.

Comment: added code to question